# this.dataset.X returns MouseEvent Object

Tags: javascript

I've run into a very strange problem.

I'm trying to create a search bar that has a dropdown button with many different search categories. Every link in the dropdown has the same `id` attribute each with a specific unique `category attribute`.

In my Javascript I used the `querySelectorAll` function to loop over all the elements and attach a click event listener which will execute my search function with one parameter (param):category attribute value.

However when the value is passed  into the function I get `[object MouseEvent]` as the output. It's quite strange because the `alert` function that is called right before the function is called outputs the correct value. I'm not quite sure what is wrong

**HTML Code:**

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="search-users-btn" data-category="name" href="#">By First Name</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="search-users-btn" data-category="level" href="#">By Rank</a></li>
     <li><a class="dropdown-item" id="search-users-btn" data-category="id" href="#">By ID</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
var searchBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[id=search-users-btn]");
for (var i = 0; i < searchBtn.length; i++) {
    searchBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {            
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        alert(this.dataset.category); // This outputs the correct value.

        searchQuery(this.dataset.category);//Everything goes wrong here
        return false;
    })
}

function searchQuery(param) {
    var query = _("search-users-query-box");
    if (!DN.value.empty(query.value)) {
        window.location.href = encodeURI("/index/admin/search/param=" + param + "_" + query.value);

//Output looks like this: "/index/admin/search/param=[object%20MouseEvent]_somevaluehere"

    } else {
        query.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of `return false` ? What does `console.log(params)` log to `console` within `searchQuery()` ? Have you tried `e.target.dataset.category` ?

Comment: `console.log(param)` outputs the mouseEvent Object. I will remove the `return false`, it was left behind from something else

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mzLyhx4h/

Comment: `e.target.dataset.category` does not work either

Comment: Which browser are you trying `js` ?

Comment: I'm using chrome to do this

Comment: Tried linked jsfiddle ?

Comment: yes that did work out correctly, however my code still does not work

Comment: Just noticed duplicate `id`s at `html` ?

Comment: should I try `classes` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting selector to `className`  `document.querySelectorAll(".search-users-btn")` ; removing duplicate `id`s at `search-users-btn` , substituting adding `search-users-btn` as `className` at `a` elements

html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
  <li><a class="dropdown-item search-users-btn" data-category="name" href="#">By First Name</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item search-users-btn" data-category="level" href="#">By Rank</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item search-users-btn" data-category="id" href="#">By ID</a></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
var searchBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".search-users-btn");
for (var i = 0; i < searchBtn.length; i++) {
  searchBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert(e.target.dataset.category); // This outputs the correct value.

    searchQuery(e.target.dataset.category); //Everything goes wrong here
  })
}
```